# Federated Learning in Tensorflow Federated, is there any way to apply Early stopping on the client side?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I am using Tensorflow Federated to train a text classification model with the federated learning approach.
Is there any way to apply Early Stopping on the client-side? Is there an option for cross-validation in the API?
The only thing I was able to find is the evaluation:

```
evaluation = tff.learning.build_federated_evaluation(model_fn)
```

Which is applied to the model by the end of a federated training round.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

One straightforward way to control the number of steps a client takes when using [`tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/build_federated_averaging_process) is by setting up each clients [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) with different parameters. For example limiting the number of steps with [`tf.data.Dataset.take`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#take). The guide [tf.data: Build TensorFlow input pipelines](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) has many more details.

Alternatively stopping based on a measurement of learning progress would require modifying some internals of the algorithm currently.  Rather than using the APIs in `tff.learning`, it maybe simpler to poke around [federated/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/master/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg) particularly the client training loop is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/3f47808a5755a41ea62297c4ae31d9bb4c96b223/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tf.py#L213) and could be modified to stop based on some criteria other than "end of dataset" (as currently used).